# Javascript - if and else code -

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i am new to coding. I actually just started yesterday.
And i have this problem with this code. I am using JavaScript. Here is the code:

```
("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 2 ) {
{
( if console.log( "The answer makes sense!" ); 
}
else( "Wrong Wrong Wrong" )
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide more information

Comment: Wow, now this a weird piece of "code".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3u3cywxo/

Comment: That code does not parse. Please provide with a code without syntax errors and a question.

Comment: I think the question should pretty much be "why doesnt this compile"

Comment: I think you want some beginner javascript tutorials.. google some and you should even be able to find the answer to your problem yourself in no time :)

Comment: Sorry guys, i am new to coding and this website. I dont know that much about coding or asking questions on this website. And I am not very good in English.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is

```
if(condition){
    //code to execute
}else{
    //code to execute
}
```

so you need:

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 2 ) {
  console.log( "The answer makes sense!" ); 
}
else{
  console.log( "Wrong Wrong Wrong" ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try it

Comment: Jonas I suggest you google some beginner javascript tutorials, they will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```js
var answer = "Jon";

if (answer.length * 2 / 3 === 2) {
  console.log("The answer makes sense!");
} else {
  console.log("Wrong Wrong Wrong");
}
```

At least this executes without errors, and I put your string in a variable or else your code would almost make no sense even if it works. Now you can assign any string to the value of "answer" and check the length.